# loading Nevron diagram in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf-controls, diagram, nevron

I have tried loading nevron diagram in winform and succeeded but in WPF it's not happening. I have read whole documentation and even tried adding few assemblies in my program, but in vain.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you can use Nevron Diagram for .NET via the [WinFormsControlHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761(v=vs.100).aspx)

You can also consider using the new [NOV Diagram for .NET](https://www.nevron.com/products-open-vision-nov-diagram-control-overview.aspx) - it can be used in WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, MonoMac and Xamarin.Mac projects (from single code base).